# Should we have a deutsch.stackexchange.com alias url as well for this site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Should we have   **deutsch**.stackexchange.com as an url for this site?

I think this is very easy to set-up. I catch myself trying to type this when I want to go here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Good idea — Done. It will be available after our next build later this evening (US Time).

Comment: Danke schön. That's what one would call reactivity.

Comment: Not sure how far you'd like to take this - should there be a meta.deutsch.stackexchange.com as well? It'd definetly play along nicely with @ogerard -s suggestion.